# Flash Failure with both Rufus and Ethcher

Tags: live-usb, rufus

Tried 2 different USB sticks with both Etcher and Rufus.
The flashing software fails and wipes the USB stick so it needs to be low level reformated and re-partitioned etc.
Have done this multiple times.
Basically, I cannot flash the ubuntu.iso onto a USB stick.

I am using an ASUS TUF Gaming A15 laptop with 8 core processor. Win 10 (possibly corrupted).
I have shared the USB stick and made sure it was RW.
I am now suspecting some incompatibility with USB speed or other parameters????
Will try again with slower machines. For now I cannot do anything more.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Try the installer USB on a different computer.

Answer (score 3):

> The flashing software fails

Are you sure the flashing software fails (i.e. it reports an explicit error), or it completes successfully but you *think* the writing process failed because Windows no longer lets you see the content of the drive?

If you get errors when creating the drives, can you report what they are?

If not, then you have to be careful to assume that the creation process failed. Especially, when writing a Linux ISO in DD mode, Windows will usually not let you see the content of the drive when the process is finished, because it does not have support for Linux file systems. So you may be led to believe that there was an issue during the drive creation, and that you have to repartition and reformat the drive, whereas your drive was properly created, and if you try to boot it, you will find that it works as expected.